# Get sql by consecutive hours

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question. Suppose I have this table in SQL:

```
date                        user_id             
2015-03-17 00:06:12         143
2015-03-17 01:06:12         143
2015-03-17 02:06:12         143
2015-03-17 09:06:12         143
2015-03-17 10:10:10         200
```

I want to get the number of consecutive hours. For example, for user 143, I want to get 2 hours, for user 200 0 hours. I tried like this :

```
select user_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,min(date), max(date)) as hours
from myTable
group by user_id
```

But this query fetches all non-consecutive hours. Is it possible to solve the problem with a query, or do I need to post-process the results in PHP?

Comment: why should the result for user 143 be 2? sorry i dont quite get it but i really want to help you solve this

Comment: Because I get difference for consecutive hours for this user, So consecutive is : `2015-03-17 00:06:12  2015-03-17 01:06:12 2015-03-17 02:06:12`

Comment: Do you have a primary key?

Comment: Yes, this table has also an id columns (as primary key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version using temporary variables:

```
SET @u := 0;
SET @pt := 0;
SET @s := 0;

SELECT `user_id`, MAX(`s`) `conseq` FROM
(
  SELECT
  @s := IF(@u = `user_id`,
    IF(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) - @pt = 3600, @s + 1, @s),
      0) s,
  @u := `user_id` `user_id`,
  @pt := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) pt
  FROM `users`
  ORDER BY `date`
) AS t
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

The *subquery* sorts the rows by date, then compares `user_id` with the previous value. If user IDs are equal, calculates the difference between `date` and the previous timestamp `@pt`. If the difference is an hour (3600 seconds), then the `@s` counter is incremented by one. Otherwise, the counter is reset to 0:

```
s user_id pt
0 143     1426529172
1 143     1426532772
2 143     1426536372
2 143     1426561572
0 200     1426565410
```

The *outer* query collects the maximum counter values per `user_id`, since the maximum counter value corresponds to the last counter value per `user_id`.

*Output*

```
user_id conseq
143     2
200     0
```

Note, the query accepts the difference of exactly 1 hour. If you want a more flexible condition, simply adjust the comparison. For example, you can accept a difference in interval between 3000 and 4000 seconds as follows:

```
  @s := IF(@u = `user_id`,
    IF( (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`date`) - @pt) BETWEEN 3000 AND 4000, @s + 1, @s),
      0) s
```

Comment: Exist another solution because I get error : `'Can't execute the query "SET @u := 0;` :((((

Comment: @HareaCosticla, check out [this fiddle](http://www.sqlize.com/0KdVP9a18h)

Comment: the idee is that when I tried to execute in HeidiSql it's works fine, when I tried to execute query from PHP I get this error

Comment: @HareaCosticla, try to split the queries into different PHP calls. By the way, with `mysqli`, you don't need to initialize the user variables with `SET`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to compare with the previous row.

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(cont_hour) FROM (
    SELECT
    user_id,
    IF(CONCAT(DATE(@prev_date), ' ', HOUR(@prev_date), ':00:00') - INTERVAL 1 HOUR = CONCAT(DATE(t.date), ' ', HOUR(t.date), ':00:00')
AND @prev_user = t.user_id, 1, 0) AS cont_hour
    , @prev_date := t.date
    , @prev_user := t.user_id
    FROM
    table t
    , (SELECT @prev_date := NULL, @prev_user := NULL) var_init_subquery
    WHERE t.date BETWEEN <this> AND <that>
    ORDER BY t.date
) sq
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I made the comparison a bit more complicated than you expected, but I thought it's necessary, that you don't just compare the hour, but also, that it's the same date (or the previous day, when it's around midnight).

- you can read more about user variables [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

As a short explanation: The `ORDER BY` is very important, as well as the order in the `SELECT` clause. The `@prev_date` holds the "previous row", cause we assign the value of the current row after we made our comparison.

Comment: I need to get all data between : `WHERE date>='2016-11-01 00:00:00'
    AND date<='2016-11-01 23:59:59' `

Comment: And group by user_id

Comment: The idee is to get data from 50 min to 70 min

Comment: "Not work"...Now that's an error message I can work with. Also this site is not a code writing service. When you don't get what the hell I'm doing here, you're supposed to ask. You should understand what's going on, not copy&paste answers. And just to be sure, it's not the first time, that this mistake was made, you have actually replaced `<this>` and `<that>`?